# Update combobox in window 1 after updating window2 Vaadin

Tags: combobox, window, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin *window1* which contains a `ComboBox` of items from database. When I select an item of this `ComboBox` I have a *window2* which appears. This *window2* gives me the possibility to add data in database. Now I want to see the new item in my `ComboBox` in *window1* after closing *window2*. Have you any idea please how to achieve that?

Comment: How do you do the data binding from the database to the vaadin component(s)? Depending on the databinding you can trigger some refreshEvents or do it manually

Comment: this is how I create my combobox : phaseStatus = new ComboBox("Phase Status");
  phaseStatus.setWidth("250px");
  phaseStatus.setImmediate(true);
  phaseStatusItem = securityAssessmentPhaseStatusRepository.findAll();

  for (SecurityAssessmentPhaseStatus m : phaseStatusItem) {
   phaseStatus.addItem(m.getOid());
   phaseStatus.setItemCaption(m.getOid(), m.getStatusName());
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh the container data source. In my case, I had a `JPAContainer` that has a `refresh()` method, see [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/jpacontainer/jpacontainer-usage.html#jpacontainer.usage.entitites.refreshing). If you use `SQLContainer` then have a look at its [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/sqlcontainer/sqlcontainer-caching.html#sqlcontainer.caching.refreshing).

If you use no special container but the `ComboBox` method `addItem`, then you should call `removeAllItems` and add the new items (by performing the DB query again).

Comment: this is how I create my combobox : phaseStatus = new ComboBox("Phase Status"); phaseStatus.setWidth("250px"); phaseStatus.setImmediate(true); phaseStatusItem = securityAssessmentPhaseStatusRepository.findAll(); for (SecurityAssessmentPhaseStatus m : phaseStatusItem) { phaseStatus.addItem(m.getOid()); phaseStatus.setItemCaption(m.getOid(), m.getStatusName()); } –

Comment: Well, then you need to remove old items and add the new items to `ComboBox`. I will adapt my answer.

Comment: If it solved your problem, [please mark it as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Steffen Harbich, please now I have a table with specific column like this,table.addContainerProperty("language_name", String.class, "");
  table.addContainerProperty("language_code", String.class, "");
  table.addContainerProperty("is_default", CheckBox.class, checkbox);
  table.addContainerProperty("oid", Integer.class, 0);      table.addItem(new Object[] { lang.getLanguageName(), lang.getLanguageCode(), checkbox1, lang.getOid() },
     lang.getOid());

Comment: How can I refrech it? I tried removeAllItem and rewrite the same code below but it dosen't work

Comment: the reload of table I want to refrech table when I add a new Item but the item is added emty

Comment: Ok, you should open a new question with code and screen shot.